# Getting Large data ( approx 10000 items ) by ajax call in Internet Explorer stuck

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, internet-explorer

Getting large data( approx 10000 items for a list ) by ajax call in internet Explorer 8 is getting stuck. Other browsers like chrome browser, fire fox also getting stuck but it comes back soon( comes in few seconds ). Internet explorer takes huge time to respond ( Takes in minutes ).

Things that I've tried : after seeing the suggestions provided online.

1) changed $.each method to for loop.

2) concatenating the element in a string once all iterations are done then finally I'm appending. 
I.e

```
for(......){

 finalList += "div"+response+"/div"

}
$("#List").append(fianlList)
```

3) In ajax call async property is given like = async: false

4) Also I've tried in filling all items in many ajax calls I.e., 1000 items in an ajax call and it'll just wait for 5 seconds then it'll make second,third..... until all are received. The 5 sec wait for the browser to get settled. Is that right?

Here, 
a) we cant show the content on ajax by typing the string in the text box, since we're required to show all the content. Because user will not be kn knowing what are all present.
b) we can't load on demand by scrolling down which loads the further data, because we have search button in case user know about a particular item and he tries searching for it then it'll not be available if that is not loaded. Also we cant ask the user to scroll further to see more data because we don't know in which call he'll be getting the exact data.
c) writing in a CSV file and ask them to mark (Y / N) also won't be a better option.

So guys can you please help me on this.Note : This happens mainly on IE(My version is 8).

Comment: I hate to say it, but loading 10,000 items at once means you're doing it wrong. You _think_ your problem is unique, but you're definitely not the only person in the world to have a large dataset. For example, the "searching" problem - you should really perform the search on the server, and return the relevant results via ajax.

Comment: I agree Christian, I'm not the only person handling large dataset. but Like I've specified, we should show all the content to the user. So search and seeing won't be suitable.

Comment: Also I've tried in filling all items in many ajax calls I.e., 1000 items in an ajax call and it'll just wait for 5 seconds then it'll make second,third..... until all are received. The 5 sec wait for the browser to get settled. Is that right?

Comment: I fail to understand how is the user going to see 10,000 records at a single page and make sense of it. You need to have an eye to find a specific record in the huge volume.

Comment: If suppose the user don't know any specific and he's going to look all in that case? really we have a situation like that.:( pls suggest.

Comment: Do you really think a user is going to look through **10,000** items individually? Even at a rate of one per second, that's **almost three hours** to go through the entire set. Surely there needs to be some kind of filtering applied before any items can be shown. What exactly is your data that makes it impossible to group & filter it?

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize it by trying something like this:

```
var html = [], i = -1;
html[++i] = '<div>' + response + '</div>'
.
.
.
$("#List")[0].innerHTML = html.join('');
```

It's a way to improve your code. I've read about this in a book and the performance increase in IE7 was **37x**

Comment: HEY ! Thanks a lot Michael lemme check and tell you.

Comment: Yeah, please tell me if it helped you. I hope so :)

Comment: @Dinesh Even if this improves your approach a little, your approach is still wrong. You are not supposed to return 10,000 items to the client in one step, that's complete nonsense. Try Ajax autocomplete or something functionally similar to cut down the number of items you need to load. (Michael: IE7 is not a good browser to base *any* comparisons on.)

Comment: @Tomalak : Then may i append 1000 in a call and making 10 ajax calls with the time interval of 5-10 seconds time on each call?
Eventhough IE7 is not a good one. I need to give support for IE also.

Comment: I know that IE is not a good base for comparisons but it's worth a try :)

Comment: @Dinesh You shouldn't try to download all items in the first place. No user needs to have a list with 10,000 items, that's slow, it's a memory hog and it's generally counter productive. Re-think your UI. Pre-filter the items on the server. There are JS libraries that provide modern things like endless scrolling or typeahead/autocomplete, use one of these.-

Comment: @Michael, even this dint help, it is a bit similar to the point 2 that I've specified on top. difference is I've used variable you've suggested an array. Anyway thanks for the help...:)

Comment: @Tomalak : Yeah correct lemme check for the libraries. One more point is, which I've created is a drop down list which has check box too. here some contents are preselected. from the server we're getting the pre-selected values by different ajax call. this we need to handle...anyway lemme see. if u hav any other suggestions also pls share - thanks..:)